# Adding rows to a DataGridView with data from text Boxes

Tags: c#, datagridview

Here's what the form looks like so far

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EoTIZ98.png]

- How would I add the data from the text boxes to the DataGridView as a row?
- And can I specify where the text from the text goes under what column?
- If so how? Because the text box order doesn't match the grid on the DataGridView.

My data grid view is called FilesGrid, but the textboxes are the same like textBox1... in order as you see them from top to bottom.

PS: I'm a Noob at C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataGridView.Rows.Add() method like this

```
FilesGrid.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text,textBox4.Text);
```

For further details visit [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx) page

Comment: I get an error...A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: this is because you have attached a datasource to your datagridview remove that and there will be no exception

Comment: Please select the answer if it helped your case so that others may benefit from it... Thanks